# why the code show write to pipe doesn't ensure atomic?

Tags: c, pipe, atomic

This is a very simple program.create pipe,then fork,use pipe between parent and child process.
and the result show that write to pipe doesn't ensure atomic.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(void)
{
    int pipe_fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char r_buf[4096];
    char w_buf[4096*2];
    int writenum;
    int rnum;
    memset(r_buf,0,sizeof(r_buf));  
    if(pipe(pipe_fd)<0)   //create pipe
    {
        printf("pipe create error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if((pid=fork())==0)         //fork
    {
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        while(1)
        {
            sleep(1);   
            rnum=read(pipe_fd[0],r_buf,1000);
            printf("child: readnum is %d\n",rnum);
        }
        close(pipe_fd[0]);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else if(pid>0)
    {
        close(pipe_fd[0]);//write
        memset(r_buf,0,sizeof(r_buf));  
        if((writenum=write(pipe_fd[1],w_buf,1024))==-1)
            printf("write to pipe error\n");
        else    
            printf("the bytes write to pipe is %d \n", writenum);
        writenum=write(pipe_fd[1],w_buf,4096);
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

result：
the bytes write to pipe 1000
the bytes write to pipe 1000  //show write pipe not atomic
the bytes write to pipe 1000
the bytes write to pipe 1000
the bytes write to pipe 1000
the bytes write to pipe 120  //show write pipe not atomic
the bytes write to pipe 0
the bytes write to pipe 0
......
```

then i want to ask what does write atmoic mean?and why this program show it ?

Comment: I'm... not sure what you're asking, and I'm not sure you are either. Are you familiar with the concept of atomicity in general?

Comment: your output doesn't match your code, and is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

Writes to pipes not greater than PIPE_BUF bytes must be atomic. This means that if you have several processes writing concurrently to the same pipe, if every write() is of no more than PIPE_BUF bytes, their contents don't get intermixed, allowing you to setup a protocol than can have several writers using only one pipe, as long as you don't need longer writes.

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about Atomicity [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28programming%29)

Atomicity should be ensured to all the shared data-structure in the multi-threaded/-processing systems.

There are some good examples [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#pipes)

Comment: @sinners If you like my answer, please feel free to upvote. Click the up-arrow next to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your program and its results do not show that the writes are not atomic.  What it means for the writes to be atomic is that the bytes written in a single `write()` won't be available until after the `write()` finishes, and when they are, *all* of them will be available.  Basically, if you can read any of the bytes at all, you can read all of them.  You don't *have* to read them all at once; you can choose to `read()` only some of them, and get the rest in a later `read()`.  If there are bytes available from more than one `write()`, you can even read all the bytes (that are left) from one `write()` and some from the next.  All atomicity guarantees here is that you won't be able to `read()` only *some* of the bytes from a certain `write()` but unable to `read()` the rest if you choose.

Of course, atomic writes are only guaranteed if the pipe's buffer has room for the bytes written -- but your program shouldn't be reaching the limit.